# Is it correct to compare double with int using the equal sign in HiveSQL?

Tags: sql, hive

I want to compare a `double` with an `int` using `=` in Hive. For example, assuming the field `score` is of type `double`, is it correct to compare `score` with an integer using `=`? Like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test_table
WHERE score = 3
```

Comment: Correct? It will execute, but will probably be more or less useless.

Comment: @jarlh Why is it useless? I want to know if `score` equals to `3`.

Comment: Double doesn't fit equals comparisons. See https://chortle.ccsu.edu/Java5/Notes/chap13/ch13_5.html etc etc. Either alter column data type, or compare intervals, <, > etc.

Comment: It will execute and if score has value like 3.00 i.e. there should be only zeros after decimal point, then only it will return true. Else as @Jarlh mentioned use comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is fine syntactically.  In fact, what "3" actually is depends on the database -- typically number constants with no decimals are parsed as integers or numerics.  Hive parses them as integers (or bigints if they are larger).

Floating point representations can exactly represent small integers.  So, you can have an exact match.  It becomes more troublesome when there are decimal points.  So a values that looks like `3.1415916` might fail this comparison:

```
where val = 3.1415916
```

because of the inexactness.

More commonly, the comparison should be within some tolerance, such as:

```
where abs(val - 3) <= 0.00001
```

In summary.  If you care about *equality* then do not use floating point.  They are inexact, by definition (that is, two values that *look* the same might have different binary representations).  The better choice is either an integer or a numeric/decimal type.